# How to prove universal quantifiers from narrow to large range？

Tags: isabelle, proof

proof universal quantifiers from narrow to large range. There are two theorems. `

```
lemma "(∀l k. l< i ∧ k<j⟶ (f l k))
         ⟹ (∀l. l< i⟶ (f l j))
        ⟹ (∀l k.  l<i ∧ k≤j⟶ (f l k))"
  oops
```

``

```
lemma "(∀l k. l<  i ∧ k<j⟶ (f l k)) ⟹
       (∀l. l< i⟶ (f l j)) ⟹ (∀k.  k<j⟶ (f i k)) ⟹ f i j
       ⟹ (∀l k.  l≤ i ∧ k≤j⟶ (f l k))"
  oops
```

`

The universal quantifier modifies two small range can be proved; can it prove the large range?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add a type annotations to force the variables to have type int or nat.

After fixing that, the proofs works exactly as you would do it by hand.